# Sabnzbd Installed on Linux NAS

Tags: linux, nas, usenet

I installed SABnzbd on a linux formatted NAS. Now the directory it downloads to is mapped differently on the NAS itself, because the path that SABnzbd knows about starts in it's own folder.

If this sounds confusing let me give you an example:

```
\\MYNAS\Volume_1\
```

That is the path of the drive on the NAS.

I would like my SABnzbd downloads to go to:

```
 \\MYNAS\Volume_1\Downloads
```

Right now SABnzbd is installed to:

```
 \\MYNAS\Volume_1\ffp\opt\optware\share\SABnzbd
```

And the default download directory (as indicated in SABnzbd is):

```
/ffp/opt/optware/share/SABnzbd/downloads/complete
```

I know that the mapping is different somehow because It is installed on the NAS, but I just am lost as to what I should do.

So far, I have tried for the complete folder:

```
/192.168.restofip/Volume_1/downloads/complete

/Volumes/Volume_1/downloads/complete

/Volume_1/downloads/complete
```

Does anyone know how to change the path so that I can have it download to one of the topmost folders on the NAS instead of having it download to a folder so deep in the drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a symlink from `/ffp/opt/optware/share/SABnzbd/downloads` to `\\MYNAS\Volume_1\downloads` works?

Comment: Will this redirect my downloads itself?

Comment: This couples the folder "downloads" to a different folder on the system. In Windows this is called a shortcut. You can see how to do that [here](http://mash.blogspot.nl/2007/11/ln-s-examples.html) for example.